# Slider should be display in home template

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am using [WPExplorer Elegant Theme](http://wpexplorer-demos.com/elegant/). Slider display in Front page as well. But if i make my blog page (Front) then i don't want to display slider in blog page.
I want that slider should be display in specific template.
Below is my homepage-silder function code

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wpex_homepage_slider' ) ) {
    function wpex_homepage_slider() {
        global $post;
        if ( ! is_front_page() ) return;
        // Get slides
        $wpex_query = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type'         => 'slides',
                'posts_per_page'    => '-1',
                'no_found_rows'     => true,
            )
        );
```

while this code is place in header.php

```
<?php
        // Displays the homepage slider based on the slides custom post type
        wpex_homepage_slider(); ?>
```

Comment: Please contact to Elegant Theme. Support to third party products is off-topic here.

Comment: @MayleenulIslam its free theme that's why i post my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removed `if ( ! is_front_page() ) return;` from function homepage-slider. 
And moved

```
<?php
     // Displays the homepage slider based on the slides custom post type
        wpex_homepage_slider(); ?>
```

in my desire template from header.php